# multiple provider call in yii2 with thread

Tags: php, multithreading, rest, api, yii2

> Is it possible to call multiple provider in yii2 with thread?

there are multiple providers that provides hotel booking online.
in rest api that create with yii2 I want to call providers simultaneously ?

how can achieve this ?

this is in an rest api with yii2

thanks in advance.

Comment: Please structure your question better. What have you tried, a minimal example would be nice.

Comment: something like multiple curl call with thread!